# Rel canonical link tag pointing to the same page

Tags: seo, canonical-url, rel-canonical

I'm implementing the canonical tag in my page to avoid be penalized with duplicate content flag by search engines. My doubt are the following:

- If I have a page COPY with the canonical tag pointing to ORIGINAL, and in this ORIGINAL page I have the canonical tag pointing to ORIGINAL again, what are the consequences? The thing is, that for me is more easy to generate the tag in all pages, and not only in the copies.
- Can i put the `<link rel="canonical" href="ORIGINAL" />` in anyplace, or should be in the `<head>` tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a `<link rel="canonical">` on the original page. There's no harm in doing so. It's just redundant but that's not a problem.

`<link rel="canonical">` belongs in the `<head>` section only. If it is outside of the `<head>` it is invalid HTML and may not be honored.

Comment: Do you mean "invalid HTML"?

Comment: Yes, corrected my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you know all things regarding how to add canonical rel in web page please visit : http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=139394